# VB.NET Docker failing with "OCI runtime create failed"

Tags: vb.net, docker

I'm getting the below error when I try to run my docker image for a sample vbnet HelloWorld application.

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "helloworld.exe": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Release .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "helloworld-app.exe"]
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like your PATH environment variable is not set. You can see what's set if you run "echo $PATH" in your terminal. Looks like it's "unknown". I cannot tell you what the path should be as that changes across OS

Comment: Your base image is a Linux image and your executable is an .exe file which indicates Windows. You can't mix the two.